# How can I get SMS verification code in my Python program?

Tags: python, automation, sms, sms-verification

I'm writing a Python script to do some web automation stuff. In order to log in the website, I have to give it my phone number and the website will send out an SMS verification code. Is there a way to get this code so that I can use it in my Python program? Right now what I can think of is that I can write an Android APP and it will be triggered once there are new SMS and it will get the code and invoke an API so that the code will be stored somewhere. Then I can grab the stored code from within my Python program. This is doable but a little bit hard for me as I don't know how to develop a mobile APP. I want to know is there any other methods so that I can get this code? Thanks.

BTW, I have to use my own phone number and can't use other phone to receive the verification code. So it may not possible to use some services.

Comment: The better way should be use some services like https://www.bandwidth.com/

Comment: I have to use my own phone number. Is it possible to use this service in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question. I use IFTTT to forward the message to Slack and use Slack API to access the message.

Answer (score 0):

google messenger web sends messages to your pc. like whatsapp web. mb you can use this feature.